# Domino Designer and Source Tree (Overwrite issue)

Tags: git, lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse, sourcetree

We have been working with a combination of Notes 8.5.3 and Source Tree since more than a year and things were moving smoothly, however, recently, after an upgrade to 9.0, what we have observed is that, the designer project doesn't completely sync with the on-disk project. Not sure, but manier times the new element/custom-control is sync'ed correctly, however, an changed element would not be replaced correctly.

Strange thing is that it happens RANDOMLY, when we open the on-disk project, everything is in there correctly, however, even after manually performing the sync operation from designer, certain times the design won't be in the right state.

It is really a strange issue and not really sure if anyone has actually faced such a problem, however any suggestions here would do a lot of help.

Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas? Anyone?

Comment: I have a similar problem since I upgraded to Domino Designer 9.0.1 FP8. Sometimes database design elements will be removed on opening the database in designer :(

Comment: I put the design of an application in a template database, so design and data are separated. If a design elemet "disapears", I only have to restore the template, no problems with the changed data.